# Twitter-Bootstrap navbar nav-collapse bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got a responsive web app that I'm working on using Bootstrap.  I just downloaded the most recent version off their website.  The problem I am having is that sometimes when I push the navbar button on my phone to hide the links they don't all get hidden. They end up overlaying the page.  I've searched everywhere for something about this and thought it was my code until I went to Bootstrap's website on my phone and had the same issue.

My question is: Has anyone else experienced this and if so have they found the cause and a possible work around?

I should also point out that I had a friend use his phone to try and duplicate the error and his worked just fine after several presses of the button so it could just be my phone, it is an older Andriod.

**EDIT**
Thought I was using most recent version, but am using 2.3.2. Will see if issue continues with Bootstrap-3.

Comment: I've seen this before too on my phone running Android 4.1. I haven't looked into it enough to know what's going on, though. If you figure it out, post it as an answer here :)

Comment: Are you able to get a screen capture of the behavior? I'm not seeing that behavior on the bootstrap site, myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is certainly Android browsers Java script parser, I have tablet running on Android 4.3 and it is fine, while on Android 3 honeycomb it is sluggish. That's only two Android variants I have for now.